# Avoid specific characters while encrypting in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass some encrypted value through URL. Is there any way to avoid some characters such as slash (/) in the value we are getting after encryption? Because in codeigniter, character such as slash is used for separating parameters in the URL. Please note that i don't want any suggestion to don't pass the encrypted string in URL :)

Comment: What i want is an encoding or encrypting methods which will not produce slash(/) in the result.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you want is not an encryption (which implies security) but an encoding. In practice, your options are basically:

- **urlencode** (Use this if you want the string to be somewhat legible. This also will give you a shorter string than the other two options)
- **base64** (use this if you don't want the string to be legible and also want to conserve space in your string)
- **hex** (use this if you don't want the string to be legible and you don't care about string length)

I wouldn't choose hex. Decide whether you want the string to be legible and pick one of the two first.

Comment: What's so difficult to understand: OP has en encrypted string (yes, encrypted. CI has a native encryption class, he might be using that), and now wants to pass it to the url. What makes you think OP doesn't know the difference between encoding and encryption?

Comment: Ya i need an encoding but which is not producing values such as slash.

Comment: OK apologies, I understand now that the string is already encrypted and then it needs to be encoded. Sorry about that.

Comment: Then you can edit this for the better or remove this inappropriate answer..!

Answer (score 7):

Use the PHP `urlencode` function after encryption: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php and use `urldecode` in the script that's processing the GET data.

Comment: best one but please confirm one more thing would it cause too long URL error?

Answer (score 5):

```
class MY_Encrypt extends CI_Encrypt
{

    function encode($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
    {
        $ret = parent::encode($string, $key);

        if ($url_safe)
        {
            $ret = strtr(
                    $ret,
                    array(
                        '+' => '.',
                        '=' => '-',
                        '/' => '~'
                    )
                );
        }

        return $ret;
    }


    function decode($string, $key="")
    {
        $string = strtr(
                $string,
                array(
                    '.' => '+',
                    '-' => '=',
                    '~' => '/'
                )
            );

        return parent::decode($string, $key);
    }
}
```

-

```
$key = $this->config->item('encryption_key');

$outboundlink = urlencode( $this->encrypt->encode($segment, $key, TRUE) );

$inboundlink  = rawurldecode( $this->encrypt->decode( $segment, $key) );
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to represent encrypted string as hex using only 0-9 and a-f and optionally x.

But i suggest you to use TLS (better SSL) for protecting your data, because now you probably encrypt data using JS so keys are visible to attacker.

Do not call current scheme security or encryption, but just obfuscation.

Comment: OP's asking how to pass an encrypted string to the url, not how to encrypt, nor how to protect data; he's encrypting (CI has a native encryption class, he might be using that), like it or not, and now needs to pass the encrypted data without messing with the router class