# How URL encrypt and decrypt in Codeigniter. Every Refresh encrypted value change

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to encrypt my url parameter such as:
http://localhost/myapps/user/profile/john
to
http://localhost/myapps/user/profile/{encrypted value of 'john'}

in codeigniter.

otherhand every refresh encrypted value change for specific data. But i need this static (unique value for specific input value always).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416814/337055

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see: http://www.99points.info/2010/06/php-encrypt-decrypt-functions-to-encrypt-url-data/

Comment: thanks. I already implements this but every refresh encryted value changes so i can't back to my original data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('encrypt');//load this library. 
$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY"; // application/config/config.php
$this->encrypt->encode();//Data encryption and returns it as a string
$this->encrypt->decode();//Decrypts an encoded string.
```

Comment: Please give more explanations on how this solves the issue